# how to drop elements and embed in jointjs

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs

I'm using JointJS to create dynamic graphs. In my scenario I got two papers. The left one contains element-shapes as templates which I can drag and drop to the right paper. Everything works great. But now I want to drop one element-shape over another one (a coupled-element for example). If the left-side-element intersects with any other element on the right paper, an event shall be triggered which embeds the new element-shape into the existing one.

I got this so far, but the intersection does not work:

```
...

//try to embed by dropping
_.each(graph.getElements(), function (el) {
    if (el.getBBox().intersect(cellView.model.getBBox())) {
        //embed element one into element two
    }
});

...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I'm going to answer my own question....

```
//get all existing elements and iterate through
_.each(graph.getElements(), function (elements) {
    //let s be the new element to drag over the parent element
    if (s.getBBox().intersect(elements.getBBox())) {
        //add a condition if you want....
        if (elements instanceof joint.shapes.devs.Coupled) {   
            //now embed the new element into the existing one
            elements.embed(s);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: do you have an example of this? I want to achieve the same scenario. Thanks!